# check if two sentences contains palgiarist words in common in python

Tags: python, loops

Hi I was writing a plagiarism detection program.

**Explaination**

Basically I am writing a *function* that takes in input as *2 strings*.The function should find if there are any instances of 5 or more consecutive words appearing in both strings.The string will be lower-cased text and spaces only: there will be no punctuation, upper-case text.

**Requirement**

If there are such words, return the longest such string of words (in terms of number of words, not length of the string). If there are not it should return the boolean False. I have wrote some code and i dont know where it goes wrong.

**My Progress**

```
def check_plagiarism(str1,str2):

    list1=str1.split()
    list2=str2.split()

    new1=[]
    new2=[]
    for i in list1:
        if (i in list2):
            new1.append(i)
    for j in list2:
        if (j in list1):
            new2.append(j)
    ans=[]


    for i in range(0,len(new1)-1):

        for j in range(0,len(new2)-1):

            while new1[i]==new2[j]:
                val=new1[i]
                ans.append(val)
                i+=1
                j+=1
                if i==len(new1) or j==len(new2):
                    return False
            if len(ans)>=5:
                value=" ".join(ans)
                return value
            else:
                ans=[]
    value=" ".join(ans)
    return value
```

I was able to write this function. I know it is quite long and inefficient but it works abit.

**Input**

I provided the following input to the function.

```
a="i took a walk around the world to ease my troubled mind i left my body lying somewhere in the sands of time i watched the world float to the dark side of the moon i feel there is nothing i can do yeah i watched the world float to the dark side of the moon after all i knew it had to be something to do with you i really dont mind what happens now and then as long as youll be my friend at the end if i go crazy then will you still call me superman if im alive and well will you be there holding my hand ill keep you by my side with my superhuman might kryptonite"
b="i dont care if i go crazy then one two three four five switch crazy go i if care dont i five four three two one and switch"
c="when i was young i took a walk around the woods i found that i was both taller and smaller than the trees returning to my home i set out for the desert i journeyed for long days and nights my spirit left my body and i left my body lying somewhere in the sands of time unburdened by physical form i watched the world float away from me and into the vast moonlight"

print(check_plagiarism(a,b))
print(check_plagiarism(a,c))
print(check_plagiarism(b,c))
```

**Recieved Output**

```
if i go crazy then
took a walk around the
False
```

**Expected Output**

```
if i go crazy then
i left my body lying somewhere in the sands of time
False
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: @PatrickArtner my code is not working as i want it to

Comment: I notice that you return immediately if you find any answer with length >= 5. This logically precludes finding a longer answer.

Comment: @KennyOstrom how to fix that?

Comment: If you change `=> 5` with `=> 10` you should get the result, which is 11 long. But you don't. There is something wrong with the logic.

Comment: There's plenty wrong. But the question is why does it return the shorter result instead of finding the longest. The answer is because there is no attempt to find the longest -- it returns immediately. To fix it, find ALL possible matches, return the longest of them. (although it may take too long) (store best_answer, check len(ans) > len(best_answer)

Comment: @iGian but then it will skip length 5 sentences like case 1

Comment: @KennyOstrom i dont understand how to do that

Comment: check_plagiarism("dr seuss wrote the red book took a rook all cook", "the best story my red ferrari can book that means it is fast so when I saw a new officer i thought that rook cant cook thats all she wrote")

Comment: @KennyOstrom This returns nothing

Comment: Yes it ... wait, did you print?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187362/discussion-between-talha-israr-and-kenny-ostrom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove all error and also solve my code thanks to help from @Kenny Ostrom.

The final code is:

```
def check_plagiarism(str1,str2):

new1=str1.split()
new2=str2.split()
# set up data structures
best_answer = []

# logic to find candidates
for i in range(0,len(new1)):
    for j in range(0,len(new2)):
        ans = []
        if new1[i]==new2[j]:
            n=i
            m=j
            while new1[n]==new2[m]:

                ans.append(new1[n])
                if n<len(new1)-1 and m<len(new2)-1:
                    n+=1
                    m+=1        
                else:
                    break

        if len(ans)>=len(best_answer):

            best_answer = list(ans)    

if len(best_answer) >= 5:
    return " ".join(best_answer)
return False
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: It does't work with `check_plagiarism('when i was young i took a walk', 'when i was young i took a walk around the woods')`. Can you fix for this case?

Comment: @iGian i took a look at the code and tweaked it abit now it will work fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have other problems, which I'm not going to go into, but to answer the specific question of why you get a short answer when there exists a better and longer answer, it is because you used "return".

Here's the way to find the longest matching answer using brute force, if the code actually worked. I got this to print the expected value with some tweaks to the inner loop and fixing one major error, but you'll just have to trust me on that.

```
def check_plagiarism_revised(str1,str2):
    # set up data structures
    best_answer = []

    # logic to find candidates
    for i in range(0,len(new1)-1):
        for j in range(0,len(new2)-1):
            ans = []

            # do stuff

            if len(ans)>=len(best_answer):
                best_answer = list(ans)    

    if len(best_answer) > 5:
        return " ".join(best_answer)
    return ""
```

Think of it like picking a candy bar. You really want dark chocolate, and I have one. I agree to give you one candy bar, and I show you all my candy bars one at a time. You can then pick the one you want.

However, if you stop me as soon as I hold up the snickers bar, grab it out of my hand, eat it and run off. Well, you don't get the dark chocolate, do you? That's what the return statement does.

I posted an answer to your specific question, but you should consider **scraping** all that and start over with this (although it may be a little advanced): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: i dont get it. Where i went wrong and where this code comes in help

Comment: He's saying that when your code reached `return value` that value is returned, and the program no longer searches for common strings, even if there are longer. 
IF you're not wanting to use his code, to fix yours you need to store the best match so far do a comparison whenever you find a new set of strings.

Comment: I was able to solve the answer with help of your code so thanks to you.